# Why does 'transition : all .2s ease, ' in css not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

So i'm creating this side bar with html, css and js, the idea is to increase the width of the side bar when clicking the menu button.
The problem is when I try to add transition duration or delay to any of the side bar elements it doesn't work:
This is my HTML:

```
<body>
    <section class="side-bar" id="side-bar">
        <div class="nav-toggle">
            <i class='bx bx-menu' id="menu-on" ></i>
        </div>

    </section>
    <script src="js/home.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS :

```
.nav-toggle{
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    height: 10%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    transition-delay: .2s;
}
.nav-toggle i{
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.side-bar.active-side-bar .nav-toggle{
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.side-bar{
    width: 5%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background: var(--secondary-color);
    z-index: 100;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}
.side-bar.active-side-bar{
    width: 20%;
}
```

and js :

```
let navBar=document.querySelector('.side-bar');
let navOn=document.querySelector('#menu-on');

navOn.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    navBar.classList.toggle('active-side-bar');
});
```

Thank you all.

Comment: What is `navBar`? Your code does not show where you initialize that variable.

Comment: Please may you make sure the example is a [mcve]?

Comment: It works fine - as long as there is something to click. Where is the icon coming from, what does it look like, is it substantial enough to be clicked? Please put up a working snippet of code which we can try for ourselves to see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working for me:

```js
const navBar = document.querySelector('.side-bar');
const navOn = document.querySelector('#menu-on');

navOn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navBar.classList.toggle('active-side-bar');
});
```

```css
:root {
  --secondary-color: #ff0000
}

.nav-toggle  {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  transition-delay: .2s;
}

.nav-toggle i {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.side-bar.active-side-bar .nav-toggle {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.side-bar {
  width: 5%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: var(--secondary-color);
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.side-bar.active-side-bar {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="side-bar" id="side-bar">
    <div class="nav-toggle">
      <i class='bx bx-menu' id="menu-on">></i>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```